# printing errors in register page using include/forward

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I need to build a simple register page. I need to validate the data before creating new user.
The validatios occours in "RegisterServlet.java".
I also want that if somthing goes wrong the user will move back **to the register page (register.jsp)** with errors that **the RegisterServlet prints**.

how can I do that?

register.jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Please register:</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <jsp:useBean id="user"
                     type="ex4beansPackege.User"
                     scope="request"/>

          <form action="RegisterServlet" method="POST" id="usrform">

              <h1>Please register:</h1>
                    <p>email</p>
                    <input type=text name=email value="<jsp:getProperty name="user" property="email"/>"><br>
                    <p>password:</p>
                    <input type=text name=password value="<jsp:getProperty name="user" property="password"/>"><br>
                    <p>first name:</p>
                    <input type=text name=fname value="<jsp:getProperty name="user" property="fname"/>"><br>
                    <p>last name:</p>
                    <input type=text name=lname value="<jsp:getProperty name="user" property="lname"/>"><br>

              <br><br>
              <input type=submit value="post">
          </form>  

    </body>
</html>
```

RegisterServlet.java doPost() code:

```
 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException, IllegalStateException {
try{  

    String address;             

    //--- Get Data From User ---
    String email= request.getParameter("email");
    String password= request.getParameter("password");
    String fname= request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname= request.getParameter("lname");

    //--- Check if there is an empty parameter or password length is smaller then 8 ---
    email = email.trim();
    password = password.trim();
    fname = fname.trim();
    lname = lname.trim();

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setFname(fname);
    user.setLname(lname);



     //--- Response ---
    if (email.isEmpty() || password.length()<8 || fname.isEmpty() || lname.isEmpty())
    {

        //--- display errors and go back to the register page ---

        address="register.jsp"; //go back to the register 
                                //page with an error message



        //adding the User bean to the request for restoring the data 
        //of the form in the register page
        request.setAttribute("user", user);

        //get 'request' dispatcher
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);        
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: I believe you can achieve these kind of checks directly on client side with javascript and update html dom to show validation problems.

Comment: @Eymen I can not use javascript. I must use only include/forward or redirect..

Answer (score 0):

You should include a conditional in your jsp and an error attribute in your response.

Code example for your servlet:

```
if (email.isEmpty() || password.length()<8 || fname.isEmpty() || lname.isEmpty())
{

    //--- display errors and go back to the register page ---

    address="register.jsp"; //go back to the register 
                            //page with an error message
    request.setAttribute("isError", true);
    request.setAttribute("error", "errormessage");
}
```

JSP code example:

```
<c:if test="${isError == true}">
        <div class="alert-danger">
            <ul>
                    <li><c:out value="${error}"></c:out></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </c:if>
```

Note that I am using different JSP tags, but the overall idea should be clear.